# Proving $\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{y + z − x}}{\sqrt{y} + \sqrt{z} − \sqrt{x}} \leq 3$ for $x$, $y$, $z$ the sides of a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $x,y$ and $z$ be the length of a triangle. Prove that
> $$\frac{\sqrt{y + z − x}}{\sqrt{y} + \sqrt{z} − \sqrt{x}} 
> + \frac{\sqrt{z + x − y}}{\sqrt{z} + \sqrt{x} − \sqrt{y}} 
> + \frac{\sqrt{x + y − z}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} − \sqrt{z}} \leq 3$$

I tried to prove that one of the expressions $\leq1$

$x\leq y\leq z$

$∵x-y\leq 0, x-z\leq 0$

$∴(x-y)(x-z) \geq 0$

$x^2-(y+z)x+yz \geq 0$

$x^2+yz \geq x(y+z)$

$x^2+yz \geq xy+xz$

$x^2+yz+2x\sqrt{yz} \geq xy+xz+2x\sqrt{yz}$

$(x+\sqrt{yz})^2 \geq (\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz})^2$

$x+\sqrt{yz} \geq \sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}$

$x \geq \sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}-\sqrt{yz}$

$-2x \leq -2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}-\sqrt{yz})$

$-x \leq -2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}-\sqrt{yz})+x$

$∵y+z > 0$

$y+z-x \leq x+y+z-2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}-\sqrt{yz})$

$y+z-x \leq (\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{x})^2$

$∴ \sqrt{y+z-x} \leq \sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{x}$

$\frac{\sqrt{y+z-x}}{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}-\sqrt{x}} \leq 1$

Similarly, the other two expressions can also be proven the same way.

Therefore

$$\frac{\sqrt{ +  − }}{\sqrt{} + \sqrt{} − \sqrt{}} + 
\frac{\sqrt{ +  − }}{\sqrt{} + \sqrt{} − \sqrt{}} +
\frac{\sqrt{ +  − }}{\sqrt{} + \sqrt{} − \sqrt{}} \leq 3$$

Is my proof correct？

$$\frac{\sqrt{ +  − }}{\sqrt{} + \sqrt{} − \sqrt{}} \geq 1$$

and

$$\frac{\sqrt{ +  − }}{\sqrt{} + \sqrt{} − \sqrt{}} \leq 1$$

My proof is incomplete because the 2nd term does not sastify my proof. May I know what is the next steps?

Comment: For $(x, y, z) = (5, 6, 7)$, the 1st term is less than 1, the 2nd term is larger than 1, the third term is less than 1.

Comment: (I’m assuming this is a contest math problem.) In contest problems, it is typical (but not always the case) that the proof requires all assumptions. If I were you, I would suspect something is wrong if my proof doesn’t use the triangle side lengths requirement.

Comment: One recommendation: Starting off with defining $x \le y \le z$
 is not correct, since they are arbitrary, but something more strict and well known in the opening that would be used:
$$x + y > z \\ x + z > y \\ y + z > x$$
This property can be easily supported by the Law of Cosines.

Comment: From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: [Here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h130812p741368) is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the second term, when we'll do the proving we'll shake hands with the expression $$z+x-y \leq (\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2$$ This is not true for the triplet $(n-1,n,n+1)$

I'll leave it for the OP to answer the reason for this.

Comment: I'll give the proof if OP says so

Comment: My mistake.. It should be $$\frac{\sqrt{ +  − }}{\sqrt{} + \sqrt{} − \sqrt{}} \geq 1$$

Comment: Yeah...it should be but then your proof brokes down..so you require another proof....

Comment: sorry to say that ..but can you show me the correct proof? I have no idea to solve it...